# ¿Como realizar un inner_join a una lista de archivos .txt en R?

Tags: r, txt

Me gustaría realizar un inner_join a una lista de archivos .txt en R para crear una sola matríz.

Todos los archivos tienen la misma estructura. Los importé con el siguiente código:

```
file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.txt')
```

Los archivos tienen las mismas dimensiones y la primera columna "gene_name" es exactamente la misma. También me gustaría eliminar la columna de nombre "...3" que no tiene ningún valor y apareció porque creo que no los importé correctamente.

Desde ahora muchas gracias por tu colaboración!

```
[[347]]
# A tibble: 14,567 x 3
   gene_name    SRR974919 ...3 
   <chr>            <dbl> <lgl>
 1 LOC110373733        56 NA   
 2 LOC110370231         0 NA   
 3 LOC110373311       760 NA   
 4 LOC110370844         0 NA   
 5 LOC110383942       316 NA   
 6 LOC110383952         3 NA   
 7 LOC110383961        30 NA   
 8 LOC110384611       350 NA   
 9 LOC110370881         1 NA   
10 LOC110383782       213 NA   
# ... with 14,557 more rows

[[348]]
# A tibble: 14,567 x 3
   gene_name    SRR974920 ...3 
   <chr>            <dbl> <lgl>
 1 LOC110373733        24 NA   
 2 LOC110370231         0 NA   
 3 LOC110373311       465 NA   
 4 LOC110370844         0 NA   
 5 LOC110383942       192 NA   
 6 LOC110383952         2 NA   
 7 LOC110383961        16 NA   
 8 LOC110384611       211 NA   
 9 LOC110370881         0 NA   
10 LOC110383782       129 NA   
# ... with 14,557 more rows
```

Answer (score 2):

Una aproximación con R base podría ser la de ["merging multiple csv files in R using do.call"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22644780/merging-multiple-csv-files-in-r-using-do-call#:%7E:text=https%3A//stackoverflow.com/a/22644983/6836377):

```
df <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by="gene_name"), Tu_lista_de_dataframes)
```

Básicamente `Reduce()` aplica el `merge()` de forma acumulativa, de a dos elementos de tu lista de `data.frames`, es decir, combina el primero con el segundo, el resultado con el tercero y así hasta completar todos.

La eliminación final de la columna es trivial `df$´...3´ <- NULL`, pero siempre es mejor revisar la causa del problema antes de resolver la consecuencia.

Si estas usando `tidyverse`, tienes el paquete `purrr` que implementa mucha funcionalidad para trabajar con listas, e incorpora también una función `reduce()`:

```
library(tidyverse)

Tu_lista_de_dataframes%>% 
  reduce(inner_join, by = "gene_name")
```